# Problem in animating multiple materials of the same object

Tags: animation, game-engine, materials, logic-bricks

Below is the image. I am animating those speaker "waves". 
In the timeline it works great.

The logic bricks are shown below. 4 action actuuators, one for each segment of the object (the speaker and the 3 waves). Now when I run it all segments become red even if the speaker-segment's mat never becomes red(and I even keyframed it to 2 black mat keyframes to make sure).

What should happen is from frame 1-96 segment 1 stays black.
From frame 1-48 second segment(first wave) goes from black to red. And from frames 1-72 and 1-96 the next segments do the same.

I double checked to see if I assigned materials correctly and I did. Also I repeat in the timeline it works as intented. So what could be wrong?

[image: speaker]

Comment: What channel have you animated?

Comment: What do you mean? I animated the diffuse values or each mat.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. It was not visible on your screenshot.

Comment: why not just animate the uv or use animated textures? this would be way better.

Comment: @Radish, the things you mentioned are 2 different things? I have followed tutorials to animate textures and they always worked. But when I try my textures something always goes wrong. Anyways, I don't know  exactly how to do this so if you want can you make an answer specific to my situation?